# Selenium - Maven - Can Selenium configuration be changed to detect browser version and download webdriver automatically?

Tags: selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver

I have to automate the test cases run confugration in maven. Downloading the appopriate Chrome or Firefox webdriver is also one part of it.

In the pom.xml under the build tag

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.webdriverextensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdriverextensions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>install-drivers</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <installationDirectory>${testbench.driver.path}/drivers</installationDirectory>
              <drivers>
                <driver>
                  <name>geckodriver</name>
                  <platform>windows</platform>
                  <version>0.29.0</version>
                </driver>
                <driver>
                  <name>chromedriver</name>
                  <platform>windows</platform>
                  <version>90.0.4430.24</version>
                </driver>
              </drivers>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>failsafe-integration-tests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>failsafe-verify</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <webdriver.chrome.driver>${testbench.driver.path}/drivers/chromedriver-windows-32bit.exe</webdriver.chrome.driver>
            <webdriver.gecko.driver>${testbench.driver.path}/drivers/geckodriver-windows-64bit.exe</webdriver.gecko.driver>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by
        running jetty:run on the command line. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
          <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
          <stopPort>8005</stopPort>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Here I have manually enter the version of the chrome driver to be downloaded and installed. But I want the oorwser version to be automatically detected in the developer's machine and download appropriate driver automatically. If I do not mention the driver version, I am getting error during the build.

How can this be brought? I need support for both Chrome and Firefox webdriver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **WebDriver Manager API**.
-It downloads the driver.exe to your /m2/repository/webdriver folder(while using Maven). It also automatically checks your browser version and download the matching version of driver.exe.

To use Webdriver Manager API,
Include below lines in your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>

<groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>

<artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>

<version>3.6.2</version>

<scope>test</scope>

</dependency>
```

-Then in your code just call this line before initialing the Webdriver object:

```
//Call any of the line based on which browser you are using.

WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();

WebDriverManager.iedriver().setup();

WebDriverManager.operadriver().setup();

WebDriverManager.phantomjs().setup();

WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
```

So you can eliminate below steps:

1)Downloading the driver binaries manually and placing in the location

2)Below line of code also needs to be removed:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to your driver location");
```

More info [here](https://www.selenium-tutorial.com/blog/144868/webdrivermanager)

Comment: Can we configure the path of the driver download?

Comment: yes you can configure the path... go through the link which has all the details

Comment: Above answer might not needed going forward. Updated with the latest available option which is available in selenium itself now. Refer my another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding latest answer.

From version Selenium 4.6.0, there is no necessity to use third WebDriverManager. Instead selenium has in built support for the same with class SeleniumManager. Selenium manager supports all the browser including Chrome, Edge and Firefox. No need to manually download any drivers as it will be handled automatically from SeleniumManager.

Steps to Implement:

Upgrade Selenium in your POM file to 4.6.0.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java ->
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
     <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
     <version>4.6.0</version>
     </dependency>
```

Code implementation example for chrome as below where no need of adding any extra lines of code to handle it, similarly implementation follows for other browsers as well[Currently it is in beta]. Refer [link](https://refreshscience.com/selenium-manager-4-6-0/) for more information.

```
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   driver.get("https://someurl");
```

Comment: Note that if you're using Selenium-Java with Spring Boot, the property selenium.version may be hard coding the selenium version to something prior to 4.6.0.
The work-around is to set the property in your POM file to the version you actually want.
e.g. <selenium.version>4.11.0</selenium.version>